# QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError from QNetworkAccessManager::get when requesting https with a password protected proxy server

Tags: qt, networking, ssl, https

I'm having a problem with QNetworkAccessManager. Here is some brief description of what I am doing:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
manager->setProxy(proxy);
QUrl url("https://www.example.com");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
manager->get(request);
```

In order to test the code on a password protected proxy server I used Polipo. When setting up a password for the server and using a NON-https url (http://www.example.com) I normally get proxyAuthenticationRequired() signal emitted. However, with https urls I don't have that signal (or sslErrors() signal) emitted and finished() signal is emitted with reply->error() equal to QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError. I'm sure that this is not a Polipo issue because the browsers are still asking for username/password for proxy server although in case of incorrect credentials they don't say "proxy authentication failed" like for http urls, just say that page cannot be opened. So I need to know how to configure qt classes or its ssl classes to ask for authentication and fix this problem.

I'm using Qt 4.5.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even when there is an error, you should check:

- the reply content `reply->readAll()`, which might contain the server generated error page,
- the error text in `reply->errorString()`
- the HTTP status code returned by

  ```
  reply >attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt()
  ```

Comment: Sorry for late response. The readAll() returned empty string, errorString() says "HTTP request failed", HTTP status code is 0. However, I have debugged Qt codes and found out that these are the results of socket errors. Http request used an http socket which returns error code QAbstractSocket::ProxyConnectionClosedError and error message "Proxy connection closed prematurely". Does this say anything to you?

Comment: @user951745 I just installed polipo and did some tests with wireshark and netcat, and it seems that with https tunneling, polipo is closing the connection if there is no credentials or the given credentials are wrong instead of returning a proxy authentication error. Even Chrome shows an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error, and doesn't ask for username/password.

Comment: Thanks! Chrome indeed shows error, I was confused how IE is fixing this and understanding that proxy credentials are needed. This mostly means that Qt is ok and the proxy server is wrong. I just wanted to test my program with some proxy server and ended with polipo. Now I guess I should look for another software that will let me test on my local computer (I couldn't find online proxy which is password protected). Thanks again!